# htaccess reference problem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /xm/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]*)\.php$ index.php?page=$1
```

And I want that when the user goes to, for example, main.php, that this htaccess redirects to index.php?page=main, but every time, and with every page, it redirects to index.php?page=index, and page is equal index no matter what. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: works fine with numbers (eg 4.php) but not with letters :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^index$
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)\.php$ index.php?page=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's rewriting again on the subrequest.  Put [NS] to the right of it so it'll only get rewritten once.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]*)\.php$ index.php?hash=$1 [NS]

still only getting index :/

Comment: Well, that's how I've always fixed this sort of thing.  Do you maybe have some other rewriting directives in operation that could be affecting your requests?